# Debugging PHP apps with Kdevelop

Tags: kubuntu, php, debugging, debug, kdevelop

I am using kdevelop 4.5.1 and I would like to debug php apps. I made a search and I found this article: http://nikosams.blogspot.com.es/2010/02 ... ugger.html which is from 2010 but I don't know how follow the instructions (hopefully not really outdated), since I can't figure out how to install the additional plugins (executebrowser) which seem to be required. Do I have to place them in a specific folder? Which one? Do I have to do something else? Additionally these plugins seem to be pretty old as well, and I am afraid they may be outdated. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, however you probably need to adapt the plugin version number in .desktop files. (`X-KDevelop-Version` has to match the version of other plugins)

Test with git master - that is probably up to date.

Read [here](http://techbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/HowToCompile#4._Get_and_install_plugins_.28optional.29) how to build and install plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm pretty new to kdevelop, could you please develop this answer a little bit further? I'm afraid I didn't understand how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It uses `xdebug` for PHP script debugging and tuning. To give you an idea of what this means it means you can use `xdebug` to profile your PHP scripts to see where they are eating up performance. Below, is how you might want to set this up.

**Installation of xdebug**

1. Install using pecl: `pecl install xdebug`
2. Allow PHP to load the extension by adding to the `php.ini` or `xdebug.ini` (create it under php modules directory) `zend_extension="/full/path/to/xdebug.so"`
3. Restart `php` (either through `httpd` or `php-fpm`) and check with `php -m` or `phpinfo()` to verify that `xdebug` is loaded.

**Enabling the Profiler**

- `xdebug.profiler_enable` should be to set to `1` to start profiling.

  - Cannot be enabled with `ini_set();` has to be enabled in `php.ini`.
  - To selectively enable the profiler use `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger` instead.
- `xdebug.profiler_output_dir` is the directory where the debug file will be saved.

  - Cannot be set using `ini_set()`.
- `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger` to `1` to trigger profiler generation of files using the `XDEBUG_PROFILE` in `GET`/`POST` parameter to output directory.

  - `xdebug.profiler_output_dir` can be changed to specify the output directory. The default is `/tmp`.
  - `xdebug.profiler_output_name` determines the name of the file that is used to dump traces into. It is by default `cachegrind.out.%p` (pid).
  - `xdebug.profiler_enable` to `0` in order to use this method.

You can then use KCacheGrind to read the debug output. You should hopefully be able to modify what I posted to put you in the right direction.

Comment: profiling is *not* debugging

Comment: well, the question asks about debugging

Answer (score 0):

I also had lots of problems in getting this to work. I wrote a [small tutorial](http://crisidellaprospettiva.com/en/news/index/php-debugging-in-kdevelop-and-ubuntu-saucy) about this with the complete steps. Anyway, it boils down to:

1. Clone the two repositories if the plugins

   git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kdev-executebrowser

   git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kdev-xdebug
2. Cd into each of them, run "cmake . && make && sudo make install"
3. Add /usr/local to your KDEDIRS, if it is not already there (see [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?61361-How-to-install-the-recoll-plugin-for-krunner-in-Kubuntu-12-10&p=317733&viewfull=1#post317733))
4. Run kbuildsycoca --noincremental
5. At this point, you should launch KDevelop, go to settings, then plugins, and you should see the two plugins just installer.
6. Configure the launches, as written [here](http://nikosams.blogspot.co.at/2010/02/kdevelop-xdebug-php-debugger.html).